# CSS in Google Earth plugin

Tags: css, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Just wondering if it is possible to style a pop-up balloon via an external/linked `.css` file, rather than inline styles ?

Answer (score 3):

What I generally do is create a BalloonStyle for my placemark balloons that contains a wrapper  `div` with a CSS class like `earth-balloon`, which can then be styled directly from within the containing page.

For example, the KML would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="foo">
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[
        <div class="earth-balloon">
          $[description]
        </div>
        ]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <styleUrl>#foo</styleUrl>
      <name>Bar</name>
      <description><![CDATA[
        Some <em>HTML</em> here.
      ]]></description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-122,37</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

the containing page itself could look like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
  <!-- Earth API stuff goes here -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map3d"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and your `styles.css` could then style the balloon for Placemarks with `styleUrl = #foo` via rules like:

```
.earth-balloon {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.earth-balloon em {
  color: red;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have done this in the past, it can be quite tricky. You need to use firebug to figure out the selectors you need to get and in your CSS you will have to be quite specific to override them, on occaision you might even have to use !important on the rule.

Natalie

Comment: Thats great, how would i go about doing so, where does the external file need to be linked?
Any example how-to that you can point me too.

regards.
.k

Comment: [This](http://www.recyclenow.com/applications/recyclenow_08/banklocator/search_results.rm?place=bn1+4aj&x=29&y=16) is something I worked on a long time ago, it has changed a bit but should give you an idea, have a look at the code in firebug and at banklocator.css

Comment: heh looks like you cant put html in comments, only in answers :) - the url is http://www.recyclenow.com/applications/recyclenow_08/banklocator/search_results.rm?place=bn1+4aj&x=29&y=16